# Op-amp weird noise (asymmetric)

Tags: operational-amplifier, stm32, adc, noise, voltage-measurement

I have a discovery board and an [ADA4528-2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4528-1_4528-2.pdf) op amp. These are connected together. PCB and schematic are in later.

Acquired data from MCU ADC of [stm32f746](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f746ng.html) is on the picture below. As you see the signal is concentrated on top, instead of being concentrated in the middle. there is no reason to the signal to have a bias in its concentration. Why should this happen? Also the variation is high for 12-bit audio ADC, I mean SNR is also low. This is obvious in histogram pictures.

Time signal snapshot:

[image: ![time domain]

I've created histogram of ADC output in two case, lef: ADC is Connected to [ADA4528-2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4528-1_4528-2.pdf) but there is no driver for this IC, the right one: Only one propylen/polyester capacitor has been placed between the ADC input to 3.3v:

[image: histogram]

I've created this histogram creation process for this hope: Finding way to compare noise is exist within Discovery board and the noise added by [ADA4528-2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4528-1_4528-2.pdf). Note that TM-004 has told the histogram of captured noise by ADC must be gaussian if you've implemented good grounding in your PCB.

[ADA4528-2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4528-1_4528-2.pdf).

Hardware PCB snapshot:

[image: PCB]

Actual picture of hardware:

[image: Hardware]

Is there any way to improve system SNR and the nonlinearity that caused signal concentration to become biased.

### Schematic

This is stability test of op amp circuit:

[image: op amp circuit]

### Culprit candidate

Maybe this amplifier character represent why too nosy?

[image: noise figure]

The mentioned info before, was acquired through STM32CUBEMONITOR, I now try to see actual signal in MCU by LTDC. The acquisition has been tested by LTDC and direct histogram calculation, in device, the histogram seems gaussian and symmetric and the asymmetric must be due to STM32CUBEmonitor, and this is bad because reliability of cubemonitor is under question. And firmware coding is time consuming. Weird noise is no longer exists but SNR is low.

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect the mean to be zero? Why would you expect to be able to remove noise?

Comment: @Andyaka the if we can not find the culprit of noise then how we can design a hardware we app. zero noise. Maybe the nature of noise could reveal it's owner? And according to https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/adc-input-noise.html it seems nice design reflects normal symmetric histogram, but mine is asymmetric. Maybe you've see this pattern anywhere else?

Comment: "only with a capacitor to stabilize its voltage" Where? Connected to the voltage reference or as an analog input low pass filter? In this case, what is the sampling frequency and the filter specs? Please share the schematics.

Comment: @devnull C is connected to 3v3.

Comment: You paragraph starting with "on the right" is not clear, I have no idea how to interpret it. Maybe rephrase?

Comment: Schematic please!

Comment: The mean in one picture is about 2677; the mean in another picture is about 2.649 so, I'll ask again; WHY DO YOU EXPECT THE MEAN TO BE ZERO? Also why are the two means I've just mentioned not anything like the same value AND why are the two histograms plotted on different X scales - this makes it difficult to make a comparison. Not least, as winny says, why haven't you submitted a schematic?

Comment: @Andyaka Oh I'm sorry I mean realtive mean. if the histogram became symteric the relative mean becoming zero.

Comment: @DamienD I mean histogram from two signal, one free running adc one with opamp attached to it. Rephrased. ty.

Comment: That doesn't make sense either. Please address all the points raised in comments and add the details to your question rather than leaving them as comments. Details that are important MUST be in the question.

Comment: @winny ok but I will add them after some test.

Comment: If this is related to your previous question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610050/adc-channels-of-stm32f746g-discovery-noise) it will probably be useful to explain what did you expect from reading floating high impedance inputs.

Comment: Asking question does not semm so easy, ok but I will back to the question after some test please let me to some dive into question.

Comment: Your questions are not easy to read -- partly because of small language mistakes like 'is float' instead of 'is floating', partly because your descriptions are super imprecise. For instance I can tell that 'free running' means something specific to you, but we're lost because it could actually mean a thousand things and we have no idea which one. And that op amp you mention in the comments is coming out of nowhere! I recommend posting a schematic and working some more on your writing to achieve clarity :)

Comment: @DamienD, Ok I've updated ;) thank you kindly, and you all.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd have you tried connecting the inputs to a known DC source? If they're floating they will act as antennas and pick up all sorts of external noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between ADC data shown via (a) LTDC and an LCD, and (b) via the STM32CubeMonitor, means that the data sent via STM32CubeMonitor is incorrect.